# How to create private notes with android Memo App

Tags: java, android

I'm building an android app which provides the ability to create notes.

For this purpose I start next activity:

```
Intent notepad = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notepad.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
notepad.setPackage("com.sec.android.app.memo");

// Verify it resolves
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(notepad, PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

// Start Notepad if it's safe
if (isIntentSafe)
{
    startActivity(notepad);
}
```

The code works fine and native **Memo** *App* is launched successfully.

However, the notes I wrote in Memo from my App are visible when I launch **Memo** *App* from the desktop, and I would like that those notes would be private and it only be visible from my App.

This feature (create private notes) is available for iPhone Apps by NoteViewController class.

Does anyone know if that is posible for android App?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the app has to be written with this usecase in mind.  Memo wasn't.  Also, memo is not available on all phones-  many phones replace it with other apps with similar purpose.  Some don't have a memo app at all.  In fact most don't-  the sec in your package name is Samasung Electronics Corp, that app will only appear on Samsung phones (and not all of them).

Comment: Ok Gabe, thanks a lot. As an alternative of the unknown availability for Memo App, would it be posible to create a generic intent to write a note, verify that an app exists to handle it?

Comment: @fillera: There is no "generic intent to write a note".